# CSS Shape or SVG mask, which is the best approach for responsive design?

Tags: css, responsive-design

Hy !

I would like to achieve this :
[image: Exemple]

But I can not ... Can you give me a track or tutorial to follow?
I tried with this model, but it is not responsive. [Here is my JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wey3jwfd/)

```
<div class="block">
   <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.block {
  position: relative;
}
.block > div {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  border: 7em solid #1142AA;
  border-right: 7em solid transparent;
  left: 0em;
 top: 0em;
}
```

Thank you ;-)

Comment: you can create svg and use it in "background-image" or in "src of img tag". that will be good. shapes created using borders are hard to make responsive.

Comment: "Best Approach" and "Resource Request" questions are both off-topic for Stack Overlfow.

Comment: Thank you for your response murli2308, @Paulie_D, sorry but I speak little English and I have perhaps not well-posed my question.

Comment: What do you think about that ? [NEW JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qnr10Lx2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I got it !**

My answer is based with the Bootstrap framework and **the clip-path property**. This solution is responsive.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qnr10Lx2/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 text-block">
            <p>Hi omnes lingua, institutis, legibus inter se differunt. Non equidem invideo, miror magis posuere velit aliquet. Quo usque tandem abutere, Catilina, patientia nostra? Nihil hic munitissimus habendi senatus locus, nihil horum?</p>
        </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 img-block">
          </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
    background:url('http://subtlepatterns2015.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/symphony.png') repeat;
}
.text-block{
    padding:20px;
    height:200px;
}
.img-block{
    background:url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=400%C3%97200&w=400&h=200') no-repeat center fixed ;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 1%, 100% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 50%);
    clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 1%, 100% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 50%);
    }
```

JS

```
$.fn.heightBlocks = function(){
    return this.outerHeight(
        Math.max.apply(this,
            $(this).map(function(i,e){
                return $(e).outerHeight()
            }).get()
        )
    )
};

$('.text-block, .img-block').heightBlocks();
```

What do you think about that ?